# Java Swing: Graphics2D rotation creating disgusting edges

Tags: java, swing, applet, paint, java-2d

I'm having a problem with the rotation of images

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.setToIdentity();
at.translate(x, y);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
g2.transform(at);
image.paintIcon(c, g2);
```

I use this code to rotate the picture before painting it (image is a class I created to help me handle loading of picture.

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with the edges of the image that become really bad (cf Picture)
[image]

any ideas how I can improve the quality of the draw ?

jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about trying antialiased edges and bilinear transform? You can see an example [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/03/10/java-2d-trickery-antialiased-image-transforms). Also check your type of image, the example uses a `BufferedImage`.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, the highest quality rendering will be driven by turning on anti-aliasing (which you've done), setting interpolation to `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC` and setting rendering to `VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY`.